# Executing a specific http method 'depending' on the condition given in the JSON file

Tags: json, postman

I was thinking about the possibility of executing a specific **http method** (POST or PUT) in **POSTMAN** **without** specifying it.

I mean; imagine if there was a field in a JSON file called: **METHOD** within 2 possible states: 'I' corresponding to **INSERT OR POST** and the another one: 'U' related to **UPDATE or PUT**

Something like this: *(please, do note the field called "method"):*

```
[
    {
        "sku": "95LB645R34ER",
        "method": 'I'
        "payload": {
            "price": "147000",
            "tax_percentage": "US-21",
            "store_code": "B2BUSD",
            "markup_top": "1.62",
            "status": "1",
            "group_prices": [
                {
                    "group": "CLASS A",
                    "price": "700038.79",
                    "website": "B2BUSD"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "sku": "95TYS34344ER",
        "method": 'U'
        "payload": {
            "price": "69978",
            "tax_percentage": "US-21",
            "store_code": "B2BUSD",
            "markup_top": "9.99",
            "status": "1",
            "group_prices": [
                {
                    "group": "CLASS B",
                    "price": "88888.79",
                    "website": "B2BUSD"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I would like to run that JSON using the Collection Runner but i have no idea how to do the trick. I mean, everytime i generate a collection **i have** to specify the HTTP METHOD otherwise it wont know what to do.

I want the program to adjust that by looking at the JSON file, if "method":'I' then, perform a POST or if "method":'U' execute a PUT method. Do you get me?

I've been reading the documentation but i did not find something like that or maybe i did not understand. I'm not an expert on POSTMAN :(

Can you help me?

EDIT:

Alright, i did this:

[image]

Comment: In the request UI, use `{{METHOD}}` where you would see the method, you can edit that field, in the file use `METHOD` and the HTTP verb as the value. It needs to be uppercase in one or all parts of it.

Comment: Hey Danny, thank you for replying!. Gonna check that out :)

Comment: Danny, i have updated my thread. Just a question: take a look at the JSON shown in my question.Is it okay to put "METHOD" outside the *payload* structure?Should i write a sentence like this: *"METHOD":"POST"*?Would it be possible to just use something like this: *"METHOD":"I" or *"METHOD":"U"?

Comment: I and U are not valid HTTP methods so why would that work.

Answer (score 0):

In the request UI, use the `{{METHOD}}` syntax where you would see the HTTP method. This is an editable field as it allows you to add custom HTTP methods.

In the file, use the `METHOD` key and any HTTP verb as the value. Ensure that it's part of each object in the datafile as you will need it for each iteration.